# A function which evaluates quickly may take a long time to plot?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

HI  I need to compute some complex integrals similar to  Bromwich inversions of Laplace transform.  The first is quick to evaluate: 0.09375, but takes a long time to  plot:6.67188

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
    L = Infinity;
    fn[z_] := 
     z^(-6/5) (1 - z)^(-5/3);(*function with two branch points*)
    inth = (Exp[ -#1  z] fn[z]/z /. z -> -1 + I #2) &;
    H[x_] := Chop[
      NIntegrate [
       inth[x, t], {t, -L, 
        L}]];(*Inverse Laplace transform at x, computed as Bromwich \
    integral in t*)
    Timing[H[1]]
Timing[Plot[H[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

I tried to use fewer points

```
Timing[Plot[H[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10]]
```

but that took even longer.  With the next two functions I needed (where I used also ND), the evaluations  took 3 and 24 sec:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
W[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Chop[H[x]/200 - 
    Exp[-x/2] NIntegrate[(H[2 - y]  Exp[- y]/200), {y, 0, 2}]]; 
Wp[x_?NumericQ] := ND[W[y], y, x] // N;
Print[" W(3 )= ", Timing[W[3]], " W'(3 )= ", Timing[Wp[ 3 ]]]
```

so I guess I  need both to cut down  the plotting time, and speed up the numeric derivative

Comment: If I evaluate `Plot[H[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0]; // AbsoluteTiming`, which should evaluate your function roughly 100 times plus a bit of plot construction overhead, it takes roughly 2.9s, whereas a single evaluation takes 0.03s on my computer. This looks completely reasonable to me: Your function is not really that fast to evaluate, and when you plot it, you have to evaluate it many times, so that adds up fast.

Comment: You can gain at least 25 percent in speed, if you integrate only from zero to infinity:  `inth2[x_, t_] = 
 inth[x, t] + inth[x, -t] // Together // 
  FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < 1 && t > 0] & `  and  `H2[x_] := Chop@NIntegrate[inth2[x, t], {t, 0, L}] ` .

Comment: When i cancel Together, i gain 45 percent.  `inth3[x_, t_] = inth[x, t] + inth[x, -t] `  and  `H3[x_] := Chop@NIntegrate[inth3[x, t], {t, 0, L}] ` .

Answer (score 3):

> The first is quick to evaluate: 0.09375, but takes a long time to
>   plot:6.67188

May be I am missing something. But you are comparing one single evaluation, with many more evaluations used by Plot.

Compare

```
  Timing[Table[H[n], {n, 0, 1, .01}]][[1]]
  (* 2.34375 *)
```

with

```
  Timing[Plot[H[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
  (* 1.8 *)
```

I did not use the same points sampled by Plot, but it should be close enough. The point is, you compared the timing for single point evaluation, with Plot having to do many many more than one point.

> I tried to use fewer points Timing[Plot[H[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints ->
>   10]] but that took even longer.

I do not think 10 in the above is the *total* number of point used. From help, it says

> total number of initial sample points to use.

Notice the word *initial*. To find how many points `Plot` actually used, you can look at the Plot output itself

```
p = Plot[H[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10];
InputForm[p]
```

You see, it used many many more than just 10.